# IE10 does not send cookies when using CORS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, cors, internet-explorer-10

I am using IE v10.0.9200.xxx on Windows 8 Enterprise.

**Cookies are not send in IE10 when doing a CORS request!**

Works well in chrome! I can access the cookies when using chrome.
The request works fine, I get the data back, but on the serverside I have no cookies.And I checked it, there are cookies in my IE10 page instance.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin and Access-Control-Allow-Credentials headers are set correctly!
Is there something I have to obey when using IE10? 
IE has always been specific :-)

```
$.ajax({

    type: 'GET',
    url: 'https://mywebapi.dev/api/Values',
    contentType: 'text/plain',
    dataType: "json",

    xhrFields: {

        withCredentials: true
    },
    headers: {
    },
    success: function (data, msg, xhr) {
        alert(data);
        alert(msg);
    },
    error: function (xhr, error) {
      }
});
```

In my web Api Message Handler:
ShareAble,Secure = true, HttpOnly=false

```
r.SetCookie("CookieName", "CookieValue", true, DateTime.Now.AddYears(10), false, "/", true, "");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a P3P header into my web api response.headers collection:

```
 r.Headers.Add("P3P", "CP=\"CURa ADMa DEVa CONo HISa OUR IND DSP ALL COR\"");
```

I didn't check the meaning of the P3P value, so take care which value do you set.
As I have read and understand, the value can be anything `"CP='XYZ'"`

But one problem is still there. With IE10 I can only get and set cookies from/to the CORS client, which my web api has issued. When I use Chrome I get all cookies in my web api!

[Answer](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/):

> The .withCredentials property will include any cookies from the remote
>   domain in the request, and it will also set any cookies from the
>   remote domain. Note that these cookies still honor same-origin
>   policies, so your JavaScript code can’t access the cookies from
>   document.cookie or the response headers. They can only be controlled
>   by the remote domain.

When adding a custom header in IE10, the request is aborted.

```
headers: {
                /// request is aborted in IE10 when using custom header, 
                /// works in Chrome issueing a options preflight request
                "AUTHORIZATION": "dev-client" 
}
```